# Handling MySQL transcations for two methods

Tags: c#, .net, mysql, .net-3.5

I want to use MySQL Transactions to Rollback changes if any of the method fails. I referred to this example at StackOverflow: [MySql and inserting last ID problem remains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542999/mysql-and-inserting-last-id-problem-remains), but my problem is a bit different.

I have a code as below:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    btnSave.Enabled = false;
    int result1 = SaveBillDetails();
    int result2 = SaveBillItems();

    if ((result1 == 1) && (result2 == 1))
    {
        //Update old stock
        UpdateStock.ReduceStock(Convert.ToInt32(txtBillNo.Text), Convert.ToDateTime(dtpBillDate.Text));
        MessageBox.Show("Saved", "StockApp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
    btnSave.Enabled = true;
}
```

I want to call something like BeginTransaction just before **SaveBillDetails** and **SaveBillItems** is called. Both of these methods are not using transactions. I just want to add transaction to the above code.

Comment: what is the problem? wana code style question?

Comment: The problem is that both the methods use independent Data Access classes. Merging all the three methods, viz. SaveBillDetails, SaveBillItems and ReduceStock, is a time consuming task. If I add BeginTransaction to the above code, I assume I am not initiating transaction unless I use something like the code shown in the link I posted in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible to use System.TransactionScope with MySQL depending on which verison of .Net you are targeting and which version of the MySQL connector you are using - see this [post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataproviders/thread/b466f2f4-4efc-455d-82c5-7c82f5d66660/)

also see the discussion on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893862/is-the-transactionscope-object-fully-supported-using-mysqlconnector-for-net)

Comment: I am using .NET 3.5 SP1 and MySQL ConnectorNet 6.4.3.

Answer (score 1):

this is a common issue, assuming that you are in full control of your Data Access Layer design and implementation, you should have a method that creates a connection or transaction and returns it back then you modify your two Save methods to accept a transaction as parameter and use it in the command execution.

Very important to wrap usage of connection and transaction with using so objects are disposed properly.