# TransactionScope with nested methods - MySQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, transactions, transactionscope

Does MYSQL support TransactionScope without passing the MySqlConnection object as a parameter?
Or does it just work with MS SQL 2008 and above?

for example:

```
public void Method()
{
    using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        Delete();
        Insert();
        Update();

        scope.Complete();
    }
}

public void Update()
{
     using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
     {
         // Update something in the Database
     }
}

public void Insert()
{
     using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
     {
         // Insert something in the Database
     }
}

public void Delete()
{
     using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
     {
         // Delete something from Database
     }
}
```

or should I do it with the MySqlConnection conn object as a parameter?

```
public void Method()
{
    using (var scope = new System.Transactions.TransactionScope())
    {
        using(MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection())
        {
            Delete(conn);
            Insert(conn);
            Update(conn);
        }

        scope.Complete();
    }
}

public void Update(MysqlConnection conn)
{
    // Update something in the Database
}

public void Insert(MysqlConnection conn)
{
    // Insert something in the Database
}

public void Delete(MysqlConnection conn)
{
    // Delete something from Database
}
```

Comment: Interesting to know the test result without parsing connection, second option will work but you can try without sending connection by using `cmd.Connection.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1893862/is-the-transactionscope-object-fully-supported-using-mysqlconnector-for-net

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create multiple `MySqlConnection` objects within a single `TransactionScope`: [bug 50773](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=50773).

A solution is to upgrade to https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector which [does support TransactionScope](https://mysql-net.github.io/MySqlConnector/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#transactionscope).